Create new variable based on partial string matching in column R
I have a large df with Columns: "Gene, variable, value" to which I would like to add a new variable "light_exposure". To assign the value to this new column I would like to see if there is a partial string match of "i13" within the variable column, and assign values of "yes" or "no" accordingly in the "light_exposure" column.
The column "variable" contains subject IDs and a typical one looks like "sem_outdir_NAi13t3n27_S4"
This is the code I thought would work. However it assigns yes in the new column even when there is not a match present.
df_long <- df_long %>% 
  group_by(Gene) %>% 
  mutate(Light_exposure = case_when(sum(grep("i13", paste(variable))) > 0 ~ "yes",
                                    TRUE ~ "no")) %>% ungroup()

df <- structure(list(rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n2_S1 = c(756.624, 0, 357.557, 
1.1, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n14_S2 = c(906.464, 0, 352.441, 
1.022, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n26_S3 = c(307.957, 0, 211.422, 
1.04, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n27_S4 = c(739.13, 0, 268.329, 
1.243, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n31_S5 = c(206.39, 0, 205.709, 
1.052, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t3n1_S6 = c(154.113, 0, 247.21, 
1.458, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t3n10_S7 = c(220.125, 0, 346.917, 
0.378, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t3n16_S8 = c(554.147, 0, 252.998, 
0.503, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t3n24_S9 = c(317.122, 0, 325.901, 
1.32, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t3n29_S10 = c(183.428, 0, 216.055, 
1.47, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t12n7_S11 = c(125.687, 0, 157.471, 
0.41, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t12n10_S12 = c(403.675, 0, 224.673, 
1.034, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t12n11_S13 = c(1387.289, 0, 429.794, 
1.657, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t12n16_S14 = c(470.699, 0, 145.129, 
0.949, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t12n19_S15 = c(401.953, 0, 164.364, 
1.143, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t12n3_S16 = c(534.054, 0, 240.231, 
0.814, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t12n4_S17 = c(420.981, 0, 204.186, 
0.866, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t12n18_S18 = c(509.926, 0, 263.276, 
0.716, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t12n23_S19 = c(603.937, 0, 249.055, 
1.038, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t12n27_S20 = c(374.14, 0, 293.112, 
1.163, 0, 0)), row.names = c("TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1", "TRINITY_DN0_c13_g1", 
"TRINITY_DN0_c1_g1", "TRINITY_DN0_c1_g2", "TRINITY_DN0_c2_g1", 
"TRINITY_DN0_c40_g1"), class = "data.frame")))


> df


Not sure if this is helpful but here is the sessionInfo
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reshape_0.8.9   forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.5.0   dplyr_1.1.4     purrr_1.0.2    
 [6] readr_2.1.2     tidyr_1.3.0     tibble_3.2.1    ggplot2_3.5.0   tidyverse_1.3.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] tidyselect_1.2.0 xfun_0.39        haven_2.4.3      colorspace_2.1-0
 [5] vctrs_0.6.5      generics_0.1.3   htmltools_0.5.5  yaml_2.3.7      
 [9] utf8_1.2.3       rlang_1.1.2      pillar_1.9.0     glue_1.6.2      
[13] withr_2.5.0      DBI_1.1.1        dbplyr_2.1.1     modelr_0.1.8    
[17] readxl_1.3.1     plyr_1.8.6       lifecycle_1.0.3  munsell_0.5.0   
[21] gtable_0.3.3     cellranger_1.1.0 rvest_1.0.2      evaluate_0.23   
[25] knitr_1.43       tzdb_0.2.0       fastmap_1.1.1    fansi_1.0.4     
[29] broom_1.0.1      Rcpp_1.0.10      scales_1.3.0     backports_1.3.0 
[33] jsonlite_1.8.8   fs_1.6.1         hms_1.1.1        digest_0.6.33   
[37] stringi_1.7.12   grid_4.1.2       cli_3.6.1        tools_4.1.2     
[41] magrittr_2.0.3   crayon_1.5.2     pkgconfig_2.0.3  ellipsis_0.3.2  
[45] xml2_1.3.3       reprex_2.0.1     lubridate_1.8.0  assertthat_0.2.1
[49] rmarkdown_2.21   httr_1.4.5       rstudioapi_0.13  R6_2.5.1        
[53] compiler_4.1.2  


Questions need to have a complete reproducible example including library statements and input (using dput) and preferably expected output so that others can run the code in the question.

Your code suggests you are trying to use df_long but you shared a df which doesn't match your code.

I suspect you are looking for
df |> 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("Gene") |>
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -Gene, 
                      names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") |>
  dplyr::mutate(Light_exposure = grepl("i13", Variable))

giving
# A tibble: 120 × 4
   Gene              Variable  Value Light_exposure
   <chr>             <chr>     <dbl> <lgl>         
 1 TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1 rsem_out…  757. TRUE          
 2 TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1 rsem_out…  906. TRUE          
 3 TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1 rsem_out…  308. TRUE          
 4 TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1 rsem_out…  739. TRUE          
 5 TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1 rsem_out…  206. TRUE          
 6 TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1 rsem_out…  154. FALSE         
 7 TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1 rsem_out…  220. FALSE         
 8 TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1 rsem_out…  554. FALSE         
 9 TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1 rsem_out…  317. FALSE         
10 TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1 rsem_out…  183. FALSE         
# ℹ 110 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

We first move the row names to a new variable Gene to keep track of them. We then pivot the data to long format, and finally identify which strings (Variable) contain i13.
Notice that, it is easier and more common to work with logical TRUE/FALSE than with character "no"/"yes".

Input
df <- structure(list(rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n2_S1 = c(756.624, 0, 357.557, 
1.1, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n14_S2 = c(906.464, 0, 352.441, 
1.022, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n26_S3 = c(307.957, 0, 211.422, 
1.04, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n27_S4 = c(739.13, 0, 268.329, 
1.243, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t3n31_S5 = c(206.39, 0, 205.709, 
1.052, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t3n1_S6 = c(154.113, 0, 247.21, 
1.458, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t3n10_S7 = c(220.125, 0, 346.917, 
0.378, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t3n16_S8 = c(554.147, 0, 252.998, 
0.503, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t3n24_S9 = c(317.122, 0, 325.901, 
1.32, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t3n29_S10 = c(183.428, 0, 216.055, 
1.47, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t12n7_S11 = c(125.687, 0, 157.471, 
0.41, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t12n10_S12 = c(403.675, 0, 224.673, 
1.034, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t12n11_S13 = c(1387.289, 0, 429.794, 
1.657, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t12n16_S14 = c(470.699, 0, 145.129, 
0.949, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi13t12n19_S15 = c(401.953, 0, 164.364, 
1.143, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t12n3_S16 = c(534.054, 0, 240.231, 
0.814, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t12n4_S17 = c(420.981, 0, 204.186, 
0.866, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t12n18_S18 = c(509.926, 0, 263.276, 
0.716, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t12n23_S19 = c(603.937, 0, 249.055, 
1.038, 0, 0), rsem_outdir_NAi6t12n27_S20 = c(374.14, 0, 293.112, 
1.163, 0, 0)), row.names = c("TRINITY_DN0_c0_g1", "TRINITY_DN0_c13_g1", 
"TRINITY_DN0_c1_g1", "TRINITY_DN0_c1_g2", "TRINITY_DN0_c2_g1", 
"TRINITY_DN0_c40_g1"), class = "data.frame")))


Awesome thank you! Would this work if there were multiple segments that I would like to check and create new columns for?

You are welcome. There are possibilities, yes. You might want to ask a new question. Try to be a bit more specific next time. Also, it will be good if you reduce your data example to a minimal basis.
